# What's the difference between switches and conditionals?

Tags: conditional-statements, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use If-else if-else over switch statments and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427760/when-to-use-if-else-if-else-over-switch-statments-and-vice-versa)

I'm sure they're fundamentally very different things, but in practical use I've never found a case where there's been any difference between

```
switch (value){
    case 1:
        //Do stuff
        break;
    case 2:
        //Do other stuff
        break;
}
```

and

```
if (value == true){
    //Do stuff
}
else{
    //Do other stuff
}
```

What are some example scenarios where one is more appropriate than the other?
How, conceptually, are the different?
Are there performance of semantics advantages?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427760/when-to-use-if-else-if-else-over-switch-statments-and-vice-versa.

Comment: Switch statements allow you to fall through in a much more fluent manner.

Answer (score 0):

They are analogous, but not equivalent. The `switch/case` statement is generally used when deciding what routine to invoke given a particular integer, and is commonly employed for checking an `enum`. For these cases, it may be more expressive and more readable to use a switch.

The `if/else` evaluates a boolean expression.