# How to execute an API from the list of all the APIs via User provided list using properties file in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter script that contains many API Requests. What I want to do is execute some/all the APIs depending upon whether the user has provided true/false in properties file. If it is true for the API it should be executed otherwise not.

Properties file looks like this:

```
#############################API Executions
#Make sure to provide true if you want to execute the API otherwise false.
API1=true
API2=false
API3=true
```

**JMeter Test Plan** looks like this:

```
- Test Plan
    * Thread Group
        - If Controller1
            * API1
        - If Controller2
            * API2
        - If Controller3
            * API3
```

Current approach that I am following is checking for every API via an **If Controller**

```
${__groovy("${__P(API1)}" == "true")}
```

But this approach does not look good to me, as I need to include an **If Controller** with every API Request.

Is there any better approach for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know how the different API requests look like hence it's hard to suggest a better approach, you might be interested in the following alternatives:

1. Instead of multiple If clauses you could use [Switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427760/when-to-use-if-else-if-else-over-switch-statements-and-vice-versa) via JMeter's [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)
2. You could convert the properties from their current state into JMeter Variables looking like:

   ```
   API_1=endpoint of API 1
   API_2=endpoint of API 3
   etc.
   ```

   and use [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) instead, example conversion code would be:

   ```
   def index = 1
   props.entrySet().each { property ->
       if (property.getKey().toString().startsWith('API')) {
           if (property.getValue() == 'true') {
               vars.put('API_' + index, 'endpoint for API')
               index++
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Also just in case avoid using JMeter Functions or Variables in Groovy scripts as it might conflict with Groovy's [string interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation) and in case of JSR223 Test Elements the value will be cached and only first occurrence will be used for subsequent iterations so it might be a better idea to consider changing your function to

```
 ${__groovy(props.get("API_1") == "true")}
```

More information on JMeter API shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)