# Alternative to enum types in PHP5?

Tags: php, enums

I have one PHP5 object passing messages to another, and would like to attach a type to each message. For example, `MSG_HOT`, `MSG_WARM`, and `MSG_COLD`. If PHP5 had an enum type, I would probably use that to define the message types, but (unless I'm mistaken) there is no such animal. I've looked at a few options:

Strings (`'MSG_HOT'`, `'MSG_WARM'`, and `'MSG_COLD'`) are bad because I would inevitably type something like `'MSG_WRAM'` and things would break. Numbers suffer the same problem and are also less clear.

Defines work:

```
define('MSG_HOT', 1);
define('MSG_WARM', 2);
define('MSG_COLD', 3);
```

but pollute the global namespace, and thus would require more verbose names to ensure uniqueness.  I'd prefer not to have my code littered with things like `APPLICATIONNAME_MESSAGES_TYPE_HOT`.

Finally, I could use class names to distinguish types, like so:

```
class MessageHot extends Message {}
class MessageWarm extends Message {}
class MessageCold extends Message {}
class Message
{
    public function Type()
    {
        return get_class($this);
    }
    public function Data()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    private $data;
}
```

This is good, I think, but is also a lot of work for what seems like it ought to be a simple concept.

Am I missing a better alternative?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A very common convention is to use class constants in PHP.

e.g.

```
class Message
{
    const HOT  = 0;
    const WARM = 1;
    const COLD = 2;
}
```

Comment: You would use this like this: `Message::HOT`. I also believe that `Message` should be declared as `abstract`.

Comment: Unless of course, the Message class is used for more things than just keeping constants, like `Message::Send("bla bla", Message::HOT);`

Answer (score 5):

I also use a class with consts for this.  I add the following

- make the class abstract, to make sure no one tries to instantiate it
- add a static array that maps the consts to strings for printing friendly messages
- implement a static __toString() method to do the previous

  ```
  abstract class Message {
      const HOT = 0;
      const WARM = 1;
      const COLD = 2;

      public static $enums= array(
          self::HOT => "hot",
          self::WARM => "warm",
          self::COLD => "cold"
      );

      public static __toString($enum) {
          return self::$enums[$enum];
      }
  }
  ```

I can also use the Message::$enums to test variables:

```
if (!array_key_exists($is_it_valid, Message::$enums)
```

Comment: Found that using the __toString for this is ill-advised, as newer PHP versions than I was using are complaining about it.  So, might be best to use a different name for this functionality.

Comment: This is illegal declaration in PHP5: `public static __toString($enum)`

Comment: That's what I meant by ill-advised back in 2010

Answer (score 2):

You could use [class constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php):

```
class Message
{
    const hot = 0;
    const warm = 1;
    const cold = 2;
}

foo(Message::hot);
foo(Message::warm);
foo(Message::cold);
```

Comment: Heh, I swear this wasn't on the page when I answered. Greg, most PHP (PEAR,Zend, etc.) coding standards require the use of ALL CAPS for constant names. It certainly helps with code recognition.

Comment: A convention like that is very important when you're creating your constants with define (though I find all-caps butt-ugly, so I prefer a 'k' prefix, as in kConstantName), but it's really not necessary for class constants. If you see SomeClass::foo (or self::foo or static::foo), what else can foo be besides a constant? And short of something really funky like reflection, you're only ever going to see class constants referenced like that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the two first answers to [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/254514/785897)
 mentionning both

- a way to do this with an abstract class
- the [SplEnum extension](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php)

Answer (score 0):

Make abstract class Enumerator:

```
abstract class Enumerator {
  static function enumerate() {
    return (new ReflectionClass(get_called_class()))->getConstants();
  }
  static function exists($enum) {
    return in_array($enum, self::enumerate());
  }
}
```

Declare your enumerations:

```
abstract class Message extends Enumerator {
  const HOT  = 0;
  const WARM = 1;
  const COLD = 2;
}
```

Use:

```
var_dump(Message::HOT);
var_dump(Message::WARM);
var_dump(Message::COLD);

var_dump(Message::exists(0));
var_dump(Message::exists(6));

var_dump(Message::enumerate());
```

Output:

```
int(0)
int(1)
int(2)

bool(true)
bool(false)

array(3) {
  ["HOT"]  => int(0)
  ["WARM"] => int(1)
  ["COLD"] => int(2)
}
```