# Using static fields as config options for methods

Tags: java, design-patterns

There's a pattern I've noticed in Java, and I was wondering if there's a name for it so I can look up implementations in other languages.

I've seen static final fields of a class used as method arguments. This limits the caller of the method to a public set of values for that argument. For example:

```
public class Calendar {

    public static final int JANUARY = 1;
    public static final int FEBRUARY = 1;
    //and so on

    public void setMonth(int month){
       //set month
    }
}

Calendar c = new Calendar();
c.setMonth(Calendar.JANUARY);
```

Is there a name for this pattern? Thanks...

(example edited to working code, been a long time since I wrote Java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although your example is wrong, I think you are looking for [enum](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: Thank you. If any one else is looking for a PHP implementation, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enums).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Calendar {

    public enum Month {
        JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER
    }

    private Month month;

    public void setMonth(Month month){
       this.month = month;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want `public void setMonth(Month month) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You shoud define enum

```
enum Month
{
Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr;
}
class Sample
{
public static void main(String arg[])
{
Month m=Month.Mar;
System.out.println(m); // Mar
}
}
```