# PHP bitwise enums

Tags: php, enums

I'm trying to do something like a bitwise enum in PHP according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/254543/178363). However, while it worked nicely when I had defined all constants as regular ints like this:

```
final class CountryEnum {
    const CZ = 1;  //Czech Republic
    const DE = 2;  //Germany
    const DK = 4;  //Denmark
    //12 more
    const US = 32768; //USA
}
```

It doesn't work when I try to define the values via a bit-shift pattern, i.e.:

```
final class CountryEnum {
    const CZ = 1;  //Czech Republic
    const DE = 1 << 1;  //Germany
    const DK = 1 << 2;  //Denmark
    //12 more
    const US = 1 << 15; //USA
}
```

When I try to run this, PHP thows a fit saying

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or`';'' in CountryEnum.php on line [the line with const DE]

So I am probably missing some fundamental basic thingy, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### PHP versions earlier than 5.6

You cannot define a class constant or class property by an expression in PHP, even if the result of the expression would always return the same value (like `1 << 2`) .  This is due to the fact that class constants are defined at compile time, not runtime.  See [Class Constants<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php):

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call.

#### PHP 5.6 and later

As of PHP 5.6, released in 2014, *constant scalar expressions* are now syntactically valid and will be parsed.

> It is now possible to provide a scalar expression involving numeric and string literals and/or constants in contexts where PHP previously expected a static value, such as constant and property declarations and default function arguments.

- [New features for PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php)

Comment: See comment on first answer :( I feel so dumb.

Comment: @Zsub An honest mistake, especially considering you can `define()` a constant with an expression `define('EIGHT', 1 << 3)`

Answer (score 3):

You just plain can't assign an expression to a `const` in PHP (or any other property for that matter) for some strange reason. You'll have to leave them as they were before.