# How to correctly store multidimensinal

Tags: php, csv

I have following array:

```
categories = [
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        ["categoryTitle"]=> string(int)
        ["subCategories"]=> array(n) { 
            [0]=> string(int)
            ...
            [n]=> string(int)
        }
    }
    [1]=> array(2) { 
        ["categoryTitle"]=> string(int)
        ["subCategories"]=> array(n) { 
            [0]=> string(int)
            ...
            [n]=> string(int)
        }
    }
    [n]=> array(2) { 
        ["categoryTitle"]=> string(int)
        ["subCategories"]=> array(n) { 
            [0]=> string(int)
            ...
            [n]=> string(int)
        }
    }   
]
```

How do I correctly store this data into CSV file, so I could have following structure:

```
Category_table                 | SubCategories_table

categories[n]['categoryTitle'] | categories[n]['subCategories']
```

If I just run this:

```
$fp = fopen('categories.csv', 'w');
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    fputcsv($fp, $category);
}
fclose($fp);
```

I end up with structure like this:
first table has correct string(title of the category), but next table just has literally word array.

So how can I correctly store the `subCategories` array in csv, in separate table column?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125922/php-multidimensional-array-to-csv) could be useful to you

Comment: Direct array to csv requires a 2-dimensional array (for a loop).  The indexes don't matter, just so long as the elements are in the correct order. The first array (second dimension), will be used as the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've just used http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php, transformed array into string and now store it into csv.