# Storing string or integer data in PHP class properties? Best practice?

Tags: php, string, class, properties, int

When implementing classes, is it better to prefer storing integers or strings as data? Does it matter? What is the best practice for data/property storage for PHP classes?

For a specific example, for a Poll class, there's a setting for logging. The options are IP, cookie, both, or none. Should these properties be saved as strings, ints, an enum, etc.?

Comment: depends on your data.

Comment: If it's an integer... store it as an integer, if it's a string store it as a string. Just because php can coerce types doesn't mean that you should make it.

Comment: This question is rethorical, no?

Comment: @CORRUPT, no, it's not.

Comment: @Orangepill, I'm not talking about coercion.

Comment: I would reference them as constants like POLL_LOG_IP, POLL_LOG_COOKIE etc... What the constants values are are not really relevant so long as they are unique.

Comment: @reformed selection of data type has 3 major factors (as for me): 1. ***Natural data type***. 2. ***Data operations***, that I might perform with stored column. 3. Data type ***size in memory*** / memory consumtion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should select the type that's most natural to the machine, namely integers.

With that in mind, a single int `$log_level` that corresponds to some constants would fit the bill perfectly (eg. 0=*none*, 1=*IP*, 2=*cookie*, 3=*both*).

Alternatively, you could [create your own enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enums).

Comment: Well. +1 for understanding this "stream of consciousness"...