# Converting php number value to words with colour

Tags: php, mysql

I am unsure what I am to search for this question so not much research has been done.

I have a MySQL table that I store scores for a pool team as 1 for a win and 0 for a loss

i am displaying the values on a table but would like to change the output into words maybe different colours depending on the value.

the value 1 i like to read Win in green and value 2 to read lose in red.

how can i do this? or can u link me to a basic tutorial

Comment: Read a PHP tutorial or buy a book or pay a developer. Your question should be answered in any book regarding HTML, PHP and MySQL.

Comment: I did state in my question that i am unsure what i should be searching for so i haven't tried anything at moment as not sure this is 1) possible or 2) simple enough for me to understand. this is just a learning project for me so i wont be outsourcing to a developer :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for introductory information on how to write a program and does not identify a specific question or problem. Please see the help page about what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There been a lot of great answers on this question of mine but if anyone looking for a quick fix in this case the following works for me

```
<?php
if ($fs1 > 0) {
    echo "<p style='color:#0F3'>Win<p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#F00'>Lose<p>";
}
?>
```

with `$fs1` being the row that i am getting the value from

Without the links within the answeres i would never of found out how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need a conditional operator:
http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

```
$output="Result:".( $score ? "<font color=green>$score</font>":"<font color=red>$score</font>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really make an attempt before asking a question on here. Giving you the benefit of the doubt, I'd say look into [enumerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enumerations) (since you seem to not want to use a simple conditional for some reason)

Comment: I 100% agree with you, i kinda knew i would get down votes as its not really a structured questions with attempts to sole this myself, but i was unsure what to search for, Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You simply can put a condition in the table, to check the score value. Supposing you have an array of scores:

```
<table>
    <? foreach($score in $scores) ?>
    <tr>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
        ...
        <td>
        <?
            if($score == 1) { echo "Win" } else { echo "Lose" }
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, no its just single scores being displayed not in an array :)