# PHP equivalent of enum in namespace [C/C++]

Tags: php, c++, enums, namespaces, constants

I'd like to organize my constants neatly.

In C++ I would've put enums or variables in a namespace (or more) like so:

```
namespace foo
{
    namespace bar
    {
        enum herp { derp, sherp, sheep };
    }

    namespace Family
    {
        const string mom  = "Anita";
        const string son  = "Bob";
        const string daughter = "Alice";
    }
}
```

This would give me the possibility to access them like

```
int x = foo::bar::derp;
string nameOfMom = foo::Family::mom;
string nameOfSon = foo::Family::son;
```

How can I implement this in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP and Enumerations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enumerations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the enum is concerned: There is no enum in PHP. You can write an array (which is in fact a HashTable underneath) or you'll have to use a (separate) namespace and/or define a class for that, given that an enum is closer to a class, I'd probably opt for the latter and go ahead and write:

```
class FakeEnum
{
    const DERP = 0;
    const SHERP = 1;
    const SHEEP = 2;
}
```

jycr753 already linked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enumerations), and it does show how you *could* emulate enums in PHP, but if you ask me, that's just taking it that little bit *too* far. Using a `ReflectionClass` just to emulate a missing construct is like modifying your car so it can double as a motorcycle.

On to the namespaces:
Namespaces in PHP are relatively *"new"*, and they are not 100% equivalent to C++ namespaces. For one, they can't be nested in the way you are trying. For that, you'll have to resort to declaring classes inside a given namespace, and accept that only allows for 1 additional level.
All things asside, I take it you're looking for something like this:

```
namespace Foo
{
    const FOOBAR = 123;
}
namespace Bar
{
    const FOOBAR = 456;
}
namespace Work
{
    const FOOBAR = __NAMESPACE__;
    include 'global_const.php';
    echo 'Global FOOBAR const is: ', \FOOBAR, PHP_EOL,
        'Foo::FOOBAR is: ', \Foo\FOOBAR, PHP_EOL,
        'Bar::FOOBAR is: ', \Bar\FOOBAR, PHP_EOL,
        'Work::FOOBAR is: ', FOOBAR, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Where the **global_const.php** file defines a global constant like so:

```
define('FOOBAR', 'global');//just to be consistent ;-P
```

The resulting output is:

```
Global FOOBAR const is: global
Foo::FOOBAR is: 123
Bar::FOOBAR is: 456
Work::FOOBAR is: Work
```

Of course, in reality, your code will be spread-out over multiple files, and more often than not, you'll only use a single namespace for that file, and `use` other namespaces (≃ `using` in C++):

```
namespace My\Core\Components\Output;
use Foo,
    Bar,
    My\Core\Components\Input as CoreInput;
use External\Component\Input as HelperInput;
```

The inconsistencies in the PHP namespacing system are well documented (google search them). But to give you an example, if I start my file with the statements above, the following statement:

```
$myVar = Foo\SOME_CONSTANT;
```

resolves to

```
global namespace (\ for short)
    ->Foo namespace
        -> SOME_CONSTANT
```

But if I were to remove the `use Foo`, the same statement resolves to:

```
\
  -> My
     -> Core
         -> Components
             -> Output
                -> Foo
                   -> SOME_CONSTANT
```

Now that may seem perfectly reasonable, but the same rule *does not* apply to the core functions: `\str_replace` or `str_replace` are both resolved correctly, the only difference is that the latter will first perform a lookup for a function called `str_replace` in the current namespace, to then fall-back to the global namespace.
Ok, with some *"goodwill"* you could argue that this, too, is fairly predictable behaviour. Sadly, strangely or maliciously, PHP does ***not*** behave in the same way when using its core *objects* (like `DateTime`, `stdClass`, `Exception` or `PDO`...).
Take the `mysqli_*` extension, for example: you can use its procedural API throughout all of your namespaces and be a happy camper, but if you prefer the OO API, you'll have to use the `use` statements, or add a backslash whenever you write `new \mysqli()`.

Ok, so PHP has its faults, but of course, we all know that much, as for your question, I believe I you have an answer now, and for me to continue this rant would be utterly pointless. Everything you need to know about namespaces can be [found in the manual, BTW](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Comment: Thank you, I guess that I'll have to deal with the fact I can't make it look good the same way as in C++ and have to resort to something else. But thank you very much for this post it helped a lot anyway (:

Comment: This answer is outdated. PHP 8.1 added an official enum type.

Comment: @Bryan Feel free to post an updated one, this is an answer from back in 2014. Haven't written PHP in years

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP 8.1, this is now possible. To use your example:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Foo
{
    namespace Bar
    {
        enum Herp: int
        {
           case alpha = 1;
           case bravo = 2;
           case charlie = 3;
        }
    }
}


// Global namespace

function doSomething(\Foo\Bar\Herp $someHerp)
{
    switch ($someHerp)
    {
    case \Foo\Bar\Herp::alpha:
        echo("alpha");
        break;
    case \Foo\Bar\Herp::bravo:
        echo("bravo");
        break;
    case \Foo\Bar\Herp::charlie:
        echo("charlie");
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

1. Enums need not have a scalar backing type assigned, but the general consensus seems to be that it's a good idea. `int` and `string` are the common ones.
2. You could employ the `use` keyword to cut down on the namespace declarations at the call sites.
3. Using `declare(strict_types=1)` is good practice. I also favor explicitly listing types in function parameters, as I've done here. In brevity lie bugs.