# Can We Restrict PHP Variables to accept only certain type of values

Tags: php

i am wondering is it possible to restrict php variable to accept only certain type of variable it is defined to accept.

e-g if we see in C#

```
public int variable = 20;
public string variable2 = "Hello World";
```

so what would it be like in php if i want to restrict type for variable.

```
public int $variable = 20;
```

so that if i try to assign string to integer variable i get the error.

```
public int $varaible = "Hello World"; //As type is integer, it should throw error.
```

is there such thing defining types in PHP for variables before assigning values to it??

Comment: The answer is a simple "no".... PHP is a loosely-typed language, which means that you can't restrict that typing

Comment: You can only do that using Hacklang. http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.annotations.php

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**TL;DR** Not directly, no. PHP is not strictly-typed. There are, however, a few workarounds that may work for you in the context of function parameters or properties of classes.

**Long answer:** PHP is not a strictly-typed language, but loosely-typed. You can give a variable any value you want, regardless of how it was initialized. So, you can't simply type something like `int $myVar` and expect `$myVar = "foo";` to throw an error. But PHP does offer a few handy features to get you to the same end when dealing with function parameters or properties of a class.

## Option 1: Type hints

You can use a [**"type hint"**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) for function parameters:

```
class SomeClass 
{
    /* code here */
}

function foo(SomeClass $data)
{
    /* code here */
}
```

`foo()` will only accept parameters of type `SomeClass`. Passing it, say, an `int` will throw a fatal error. This doesn't work in PHP < 7 if the parameters are intended to be base types, like `int`, `string`, etc., so you can't do `function foo(int $data) {...}`. That said, there are a few libraries out there that attempt to force it to work at the expense of a little speed. Also, PHP 7 adds a lot of support for this kind of thing, as does the Hack language based on PHP.

**Pros:**

- Easy
- Intuitive

**Cons:**

- Only works for program-defined classes
- Unavailable for base types

## Option 2: Getters and Setters

You can also use getters and setters, like so:

```
class SomeClass 
{
    private $foo = 0;

    function setFoo($val = 0)
    {
        // force it to be an int
        if (is_integer($val) {
            $this->foo = $val;
        } else {
            // throw an error, raise an exception, or otherwise respond
        }
    }
}
```

**Pros:**

- Relatively easy
- Relatively intuitive

**Cons:**

- Only works in program-defined classes
- Unavailable for base types
- Requires lots of code

## Option 3: Magic Methods

This method is my favorite, but also the most complicated. Use the [**`__set()` magic method**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) to deal with class properties.

```
class MyClass {
    private $type = 0; // we will force this to be an int
    private $string = ''; // we will force this to be a string
    private $arr = array(); // we will force this to be an array
    private $percent = 0; // we will force this to be a float in the range 0..100
    
    function __set($name, $value) {
        switch ($name) {
            case "type":
                $valid = is_integer($value);
                break;
            case "string":
                $valid = is_string($value);
                break;
            case "arr":
                $valid = is_array($value);
                break;
            case "percent":
                $valid = is_float($value) && $value >= 0 && $value <= 100;
                break;
            default:
                $valid = true; // allow all other attempts to set values (or make this false to deny them)
        }
        
        if ($valid) {
            $this->{$name} = $value;

            // just for demonstration
            echo "pass: Set \$this->$name = ";
            var_dump($value);
        } else {
            // throw an error, raise an exception, or otherwise respond

            // just for demonstration
            echo "FAIL: Cannot set \$this->$name = ";
            var_dump($value);
        }
    }
}

$myObject = new MyClass();
$myObject->type = 1; // okay
$myObject->type = "123"; // fail
$myObject->string = 1; // fail
$myObject->string = "123"; // okay
$myObject->arr = 1; // fail
$myObject->arr = "123"; // fail
$myObject->arr = array("123"); // okay
$myObject->percent = 25.6; // okay
$myObject->percent = "123"; // fail
$myObject->percent = array("123"); // fail
$myObject->percent = 123456; // fail
```

**Pros:**

- Relatively easy
- Intuitive
- Extremely powerful: one setter to rule them all

**Cons:**

- Only works in program-defined classes
- Unavailable for base types
- Requires lots of `switch`ing or `if`/`else` logic
- Can cause problems with IDEs not auto-completing property types correctly

Here's a [**demo of this approach**](http://ideone.com/PWLwHm).

## Closing Thoughts

Finally, if you're using an IDE like PHPStorm, don't forget about PHPDoc type hints:

```
/* @var integer */
$foo = 0; // will result in warnings if the IDE is configured properly and you try to do something like substr($foo, 1, 4);
```

And if you *really* want to go hard core, you can do strong typing using [Hack](http://hacklang.org/), at the expense of making your code less portable and less compatible (for now) with major IDEs.

Of course, none of these is a substitute for explicitly validating user input and thoroughly testing the application's response to unexpected input types.

Comment: PHPStorm is __the__ IDE for PHP. thanks for mentioning this. +1.

Comment: @AyeshK :) No argument; it's the only one I have found useful.

Answer (score 4):

No. PHP is not a strictly typed language. You can however use [`type hints`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) in functions and methods.

> If class or interface is specified as type hint then all its children or implementations are allowed too.
>
> Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string. Resources and Traits are not allowed either.

The Scalar types being:

- `string`
- `bool`
- `int`
- `float`

Examples:

```
function (array $theArr) {
  // body
}

class X {
  public function __construct(SomeOtherClass $arg) {
    // body
  }

  public function setFoo(Foo $foo) {

  }
}
```

See the manual for more specifics: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: And for int and string ?

Comment: Nope, not for `int`, `string` `bool`, `float`.

Comment: I know it, but maybe it should be included in your answer ;)

Comment: Worth pointing out the ***experimental*** auto-boxing-esque [SPL Types Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl-types.php)?

Comment: array (case insensitive) and class names only.

Answer (score 0):

You have to made it by your own hands, example :

```
function setInt(&$var, $value) {
    if(!is_integer($value) {
        throw new Exception("Integer wanted " . gettype($value) . " received");
    }
    $var = $value;
}
```