# Laravel IN Validation or Validation by ENUM Values

Tags: php, validation, laravel, enums

I'm initiating in Laravel. 
I searched and not found how to validate data with some ENUM values. On below code I need that `type` must be just `DEFAULT` or `SOCIAL`. One or other:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::only(['username', 'password', 'type']), [
    'type' => '', // DEFAULT or SOCIAL values
    'username' => 'required|min:6|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|max:255'
]);
```

Is possible?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

***in:DEFAULT,SOCIAL***
The field under validation must be included in the given list of values.

***not_in:DEFAULT,SOCIAL***
The field under validation must not be included in the given list of values.

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::only(['username', 'password', 'type']), [
    'type' => 'in:DEFAULT,SOCIAL', // DEFAULT or SOCIAL values
    'username' => 'required|min:6|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|max:255'
]);
```

Comment: how about using values with utf-8 chars ?

Comment: what about `Default`, `Social`, `DeFauLt`, `social`?

Comment: @JustinMoh I belive that in and not_in validations must be the exactly values, for your case regex validation works fine.

Comment: @JustinMoh you can convert your request input into uppercase and validate.

Answer (score 85):

## Laravel 9+

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-enum

```php
use App\Enums\ServerStatus;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Enum;
 
$request->validate([
    'status' => [new Enum(ServerStatus::class)],
]);
```

Enum:

```php
namespace App\Enums;

enum ServerStatus: string {
    case ACTIVE = 'active';
    case INACTIVE = 'inactive';
}
```

Required PHP 8.1+

Comment: please add how  should the `ServerStatus` enum look like , is it a php enum or just an array ?!

Comment: Do you also know how to make the enum values case insensitive?

Comment: Commenting here to remember everyone to add the Accept: application/json header to your requests so you can receive a 422 error with it's respective message as otherwise you'll get a 404 or the base page.

Answer (score 36):

The accepted answer is OK, but I want to add **how to set the `in` rule to use existing constants or array of values**.

So, if you have:

```
class MyClass {
  const DEFAULT = 'default';
  const SOCIAL = 'social';
  const WHATEVER = 'whatever';
  ...
```

You can make a validation rule by using `Illuminate\Validation\Rule`'s `in` method:

```
'type' => Rule::in([MyClass::DEFAULT, MyClass::SOCIAL, MyClass::WHATEVER])
```

Or, if You have those values already grouped in an array, you can do:

```
class MyClass {
  const DEFAULT = 'default';
  const SOCIAL = 'social';
  const WHATEVER = 'whatever';
  public static $types = [self::DEFAULT, self::SOCIAL, self::WHATEVER];
```

and then write the rule as:

```
'type' => Rule::in(MyClass::$types)
```

Comment: where would you create and how would you name MyClass example in a Laravel project?

Comment: @MarceloFonseca you could put these fields on a Model class, or separate them into their own class. In OP's example, I guess the separate class could be called `Login` or `LoginType`. [Here (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25705982/2101117) is an example of where and how can you create enums. That might also help :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the **Rule** class as te [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-in) indicates.
For example, having the following definition in a migration:

```
$table->enum('letter',['a','b','c']);
```

Now your rules for your FormRequest should put:

```
class CheckInRequest extends FormRequest
{ 
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'letter'=>[
                'required',
                 Rule::in(['a', 'b','c']),
             ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Where `Rule::in (['a', 'b', 'c'])`, must contain the values of your field of type "**enun**"

This is working fine for me on Laravel 8.x

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 9 php8.1

```
$request->validate([
    'type' => [new Enum(TypeEnum::class)],
]);
```

Less or Equal php 8

you can own enum

```
class BaseEnum
{
    /**
     * Returns class constant values
     * @return array
     */
    public static function toArray(): array
    {
        $class = new \ReflectionClass(static::class);

        return array_values($class->getConstants());
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return implode(',', static::toArray());
    }
}
```

Child enum

```
class TypeEnum extends BaseEnum
{
    public const DEFAULT = 'default';
    public const SOCIAL = 'social';
}
```

in validation u can use it in two different ways

*first*

```
$request->validate([
        'type' => 'in:' . new TypeEnum(),
    ]);
```

*second*

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

    $request->validate([
                'type' => Rule::in(TypeEnum::toArray())
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel

```
//migration
    $table->enum('type',[true, false])->default(true);

//controller
    $request->validate([
       'type' => ['required','in:true,false']
    ]);
```