# Enum values validate on Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Could I use below validation way or similar of Laravel in Livewire?

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'zones' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in(['first-zone', 'second-zone']),
    ],
]);
```

or

```
starts_with:foo,bar,...
```

Current code didn't work correctly, during in the testing it just passed when I revised a html value by Chrom Inspection.

> View

```
...
<input wire:model=size type="radio" value="BICYCLE" name="BICYCLE"/>
<input wire:model=size type="radio" value="CAR" name="CAR"/>
<input wire:model=size type="radio" value="CAR" name="BOAT"/>
...
<button wire:click="checkVehicle">Check</button>
---
```

> Livewire Component

```
public function checkVehicle()
{
    $this->validate([
        'size' => 'required|string|starts_with:BICYCLE,CAR,BOAT'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: try using a form submit instead of a button click.

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976658/laravel-in-validation-or-validation-by-enum-values/55298089

Comment: I need Livewire way instead in Laravel. thx.

Answer (score 2):

If you use php8.1 and up with backed enums you can use the [Enum Validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-enum), it is available in laravel 8.x and up

```php
use App\Enums\Zones;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Enum;

class ZoneForm extends \Livewire\Component
{
    protected function rules() : array
    {
        // The value 'status' is required and must be defined in the Zones enum
        return $request->validate([
            'status' => ['required', new Enum(Zones::class)],
        ]);
    }

    /** ... */
}
```

Example how the Zones enum could look

```php
namespace App\Enums;

enum Zones: string
{
    case FirstZone = 'first-zone';
    case SecondZone = 'second-zone';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `rules()` as a method instead of property

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'zones' => ['required', Rule::in(['first-zone', 'second-zone'])],
    ];
}

public function checkVehicle()
{
    $this->validate();
}
```