# Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateEnum does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem with the `genre` column during my form validation tests: **Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateEnum does not exist.**

[image]

- `FighterRequest.php`

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Requests;
    
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
    
    class FighterRequest extends FormRequest
    {
        /**
         * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function authorize()
        {
            return true;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array<string, mixed>
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'name' => 'required|max:30',
                'martial_art' => 'required|max:50',
                'nationality' => 'required|max:30',
                'genre' => 'required|enum',
                'height' => 'required|numeric',
                'weight' => 'required|numeric',
            ];
        }
        public function messages()
        {
            return[
                'name.required' => 'It's mandatory to define the name of the Fighter..',
                'name.max' => 'Fighter name must contain a maximum of 30 characters.',
                'martial_art.required' => 'It's mandatory to define the martial art of the Fighter.',
                'martial_art.max' => 'Fighter martial art must contain a maximum of 50 characters.',
                'nacionality.required' => 'It's mandatory to define the nationality of the Fighter.',
                'nacionality.max' => 'The Fighter's nationality must contain a maximum of 30 characters.',
                'genre.required' => 'It's mandatory to set the Fighter genre.',
                'genre.enum' => 'Fighter gender must be Male or Female.',
                'height.required' => 'It's mandatory to set the height of the Fighter.',
                'height.numeric' => 'Fighter height must be a numeric value.',
                'weight.required' => 'It is mandatory to set the Fighter weight.',
                'weight.numeric' => 'Fighter weight must be a numeric value.',
            ];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71057706/12983786) help you ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel IN Validation or Validation by ENUM Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976658/laravel-in-validation-or-validation-by-enum-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Laravel documentation on the [enum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-enum) rule:

> The Enum rule is a class based rule that validates whether the field
> under validation contains a valid enum value. The Enum rule accepts
> the name of the enum as its only constructor argument

Meaning you can't use it in the way you are. How is it to know the type of `enum` you're referring to etc.? Instead, use it as a class and pass your `enum` class to it as a parameter of its constructor:

```
'genre' => ['required', new Enum(Genre::class)],
```

**Update**

Ensure you've defined your `enum` correctly:

```
enum Genre: string
{
    case Male = 'Male';
    case Female = 'Female';
}
```

Then you should be fine to use it in your validation (don't forget to include a `use` statement in your `FormRequest` class).

A [working example](https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/0hbf6?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=) for you.

Comment: The selected genero is invalid. Even if I choose male or female, this message appears.

Comment: @DevoloperBebop Are you sending `genre` as a `string` (i.e. `male`, `female`) or as an `integer` (i.e. `0`, `1`)? It should be sent and compared as an `integer`.

Comment: ```$table->enum('genre', ['Male', 'Female']);```

Comment: @DevoloperBebop Yes but how are you passing the value of your `enum` in your form request? Is it sent as a string or as an integer?

Comment: @DevoloperBebop Additionally, how have you declared your `enum` in your code?

Comment: is of type string.

Comment: @DevoloperBebop See my update and working example.

Comment: use App\Enums\Genre;

Comment: Genre.php -> <?php

namespace App\Enums;

enum Genre : string
{
    case Male = 'Male';
    case Female = 'Female';
}

Comment: new Enum(Genre::class)]

Comment: @DevoloperBebop What are you trying to tell me? Your cryptic short messages dumping code mean nothing to me. Delete the comments and add another comment with more detail please. I can't help you otherwise.

Comment: ```'genre.enum' => 'Fighter gender must be Male or Female.'``` It doesn't show up for me, what it returns is ```The selected genre is invalid.```

Comment: @DevoloperBebop If the `name` of your form field is `genre`, then your validation rule should be `genre` **not** `genre.enum`. Look at my example ...

Comment: Thanks, now everything works as I want.

Answer (score 1):

`Enum` is a class based rule, and requires you to specify the Enum's type.

For example, let's say your enum is of type `Gender`:

```php
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'name' => 'required|max:30',
                'martial_art' => 'required|max:50',
                'nationality' => 'required|max:30',
                'genre' => [
                    'required',
                    new Enum(Gender::class), // update with your actual class name
                ],
                'height' => 'required|numeric',
                'weight' => 'required|numeric',
            ];
        }
```

Comment: ```use App\Enums\ServerStatus;```, ```use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Enum;``` and ```new Enum(ServerStatus::class)```?

Comment: The selected genero is invalid. Even if I choose male or female, this message appears.