# PHP enforce function parameter to be in_array()

Tags: php, oop, type-hinting

Say, I have a class with consts like so,

```
class Car
   {
      // Types
      const TYPE_SALOON = "Saloon";
      const TYPE_HATCHBACK = "Hatchback";
      ...

     public static function validTypes() {
          return array(
             static::TYPE_SALOON,
             static::TYPE_HATCHBACK,
             ...
          );
      }
 }
```

I need the constructor to accept an input argument called type, which exits in the array returned by validTypes(). The way I'd normally do this is:

```
function __construct($type, ...) {
    if(!in_array($type, static::validTypes())) {
        // Throw Exception
    }
}
```

What's a more elegant way to do this?

Is there a way to do this with typeHinting?

Comment: Not really. You pretty much need to resort to the solution you proposed there.

Comment: No, you can't typehint it in any way unless you used a CarType class; you need to test for this in your code in exactly the way you're doing

Comment: @sergio `threw` is the past tense of throw, e.g. `I threw that stick for my dog`. `Through` is the word you're looking for, e.g. `I need to look through Stack Overflow for an answer to my problem`.

Comment: Thanks Frank, Mark and sergio. 
php-arg-validator does provide a lot of options. I was thinking of enums with PHP and found this-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enumerations

Comment: @Styphon and sergio, And I'll edit the question asking "Difference between threw and through", and who knows, maybe some moderator will migrate this question to english.stackexchange.com.