# mysql, sort (roll) days in enum starting from 'today'

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, enums

I have:

```
enum('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')<BR>
```

I'd like to be able to sort, starting with 'today' or date(date_format(%a))

Is there a way to address the index of enum and kind-of do a ROL? 
(sorry, old-school assembly language there)
Or, is it easier to do in PHP first?
currently I just have a regular

```
SORT BY students.day (the enum field)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enumerations

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in SQL like this:

```
select * from sortday
order by 
   (myday + DAYOFWEEK(NOW())) MOD 7;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> select * from sortday;
+----+-------+----------------+
| id | myday | val            |
+----+-------+----------------+
|  1 | Mon   | Text from mo   |
|  2 | Tue   | text from Tue  |
|  3 | Wed   | Text from Wed  |
|  4 | Thu   | day Tue        |
|  5 | Fri   | this is friday |
|  6 | Sat   | its sat        |
|  7 | Sun   | ist sunday     |
+----+-------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from sortday order by (myday + DAYOFWEEK(NOW())) MOD 7;
+----+-------+----------------+
| id | myday | val            |
+----+-------+----------------+
|  3 | Wed   | Text from Wed  |
|  4 | Thu   | day Tue        |
|  5 | Fri   | this is friday |
|  6 | Sat   | its sat        |
|  7 | Sun   | ist sunday     |
|  1 | Mon   | Text from mo   |
|  2 | Tue   | text from Tue  |
+----+-------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I tried both a number and "Fri" for 'myday' but the order came up the same.  Perhaps it's the way I have it set up, which I'm not married to:

Comment: `CREATE TABLE `days` (
  `daynum` tinyint(1) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `day` enum('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`daynum`)
)
INSERT INTO `days` VALUES(1, 'Mon');
INSERT INTO `days` VALUES(2, 'Tue');
INSERT INTO `days` VALUES(3, 'Wed');
INSERT INTO `days` VALUES(4, 'Thu');
INSERT INTO `days` VALUES(5, 'Fri');
INSERT INTO `days` VALUES(6, 'Sat');`