# PHP enumeration with variable

Tags: php, enums

Trying to use the code below, which was originally  provided in this question: [PHP and Enumerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enumerations), but running into a problem.

```
abstract class DaysOfWeek
{
const Sunday = 0;
const Monday = 1;
// etc.
}

$today = DaysOfWeek::Sunday;
```

How do I call that method (or whatever it is) with a variable (instead of Sunday I have a variable $day, which has the value of Sunday). Have tried `$today = DaysOfWeek::{$day};`, but it produces an error.

Comment: Show us the code to demonstrate what you are trying to do, along with your expected result

Comment: In your case, you would need an expression like `constant("DaysOfWeek::$day")`