# PHP enumeration set

Tags: php, enums

It is possible to create **sets of enumeration types** in PHP like in Delphi?

I want to create a set of options for a component like [required, readonly, ...]. I've seen [PHP and Enumerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enumerations) but it does not solve my problem completely.

For intance, in Delhpi you can do something like:

```
type enum_options = (required, readonly, ...); // Enumerated type
options_for_my_component := [required, readonly];
...
if (required in options_for_my_component) then
   ...
```

More info at http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Sets

Comment: "but it does not solve my problem completely" <- how so?

Comment: @Jeto: According to the example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enumerations I cannot see how to do, for instance: `working_days = [Monday, Tuesday, ..];` (this is a set of enumeration) and then `if (today in working_days) then ...`. Notice I'm using Pascal style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still a bit unsure what you're missing from PHP here. Using [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/in_array) it should be pretty straightforward (unless I missed something):

```
abstract class DaysOfWeek
{
  const Sunday = 0;
  const Monday = 1;
  const Tuesday = 2;
  const Wednesday = 3;
  const Thursday = 4;
  const Friday = 5;
  const Saturday = 6;
}

$working_days = [DaysOfWeek::Monday, DaysOfWeek::Tuesday, DaysOfWeek::Wednesday, DaysOfWeek::Thursday, DaysOfWeek::Friday];
$today = (int)date('w');

echo in_array($today, $working_days) ? 'Today is a working day!' : 'Today is a weekend day!';
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/RJg9B**

(You can try this demo tomorrow and it should say it's a working day :))

Comment: Yes, great! I didn't think about the array approach. This is what I need. Thank you very much