# PHP - Assigning a string value to a variable that is type hinted as an enum

Tags: php

I have some PHP snippets for an application I am trying to restrict inputs coming from a request in the front end of my JavaScript application.   The page sends a request using JSON object which contains a field value present that I assign as 'Open', 'Complete', or 'Closed'.  I want to prevent unwanted input tampering or values to be sent through.

Question:

**Below property $eventstatus is type hinted with the enum, but when I assign the string value inside `$array['EventStatus']` PHP (7.4.9) reports an error that my types are not compatible.  It needs to see a Status type when in fact I am assigning it a string.

How do I fix this?**

```
$event->eventstatus = $array['EventStatus'];
```

Enum class (Status)

```
<?php
    namespace app\enums;

    abstract class Status
    {
        const Open = 'Open';
        const Complete = 'Complete';
        const Closed = 'Closed';
    }
```

Mapper Class Member Function - snippet,  code below takes an array value and maps it to a class property

```
<?php
    function mapFromArray($event, $array) {
        if (!is_null($array['EventStatus'])) $event->eventstatus = $array['EventStatus'];   
    }
```

Model Class

```
<?php
    namespace data\model;
    use app\enums\Status;

    class Event
    {
        public $eventid;  
        public $riskid;        
        public $eventtitle;
        public Status $eventstatus;
    }
```

Comment: What is `$array['EventStatus']` ?

Comment: Presently I have assigned it a string value either 'Open', 'Complete', or 'Closed' based on completion of values in input fields and a clicking on a submit button.     $array contains the JSON values from the front end application.   My objective is to prevent invalid string values from being sent to the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enumerations on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/enumerations-on-php)

Comment: Why not using a simple array that holds the valid values and use `in_array()` ? A `Status` is not a `string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type hint actually tells PHP that you expect `$eventstatus` to be an *instance* of `Status`. But the values are actually just simple strings: `'Open'`, `'Complete'` and `'Closed'`.
So the correct type hint would be:

```php
<?php
    namespace data\model;
    use app\enums\Status;

    class Event
    {
        // ...
        public string $eventstatus;
    }
```

But with this PHP accepts *any* `string` and not only a "valid" one. Using proper Enums here would help but currently PHP 7 has no native support for Enums (which is [implemented for PHP 8.1 though](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/enumerations)).

If you want to use the `Status` class for more readable code you can just change the type hint to `string`.

If you want to validate the input data you could extend the code like this:

```php
<?php
    namespace app\enums;

    abstract class Status
    {
        const Open = 'Open';
        const Complete = 'Complete';
        const Closed = 'Closed';
        const Valid_Statuses = [
                self::Open,
                self::Complete,
                self::Closed,
        ];
    }
```

```php
function mapFromArray($event, $array) {
    if (!is_null($array['EventStatus'])) {
        if (in_array($array['EventStatus'], Status::Valid_Statuses)) {
            $event->eventstatus = $array['EventStatus'];
        } else {
            // handle invalid status value here
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use strict type hinting to ensure validity everywhere you'd need to wrap the value into a instance of the class, e.g.:

```php
namespace app\enums;

abstract class Status
{
    const Open = 'Open';
    const Complete = 'Complete';
    const Closed = 'Closed';
    const Valid_Statuses = [
        self::Open,
        self::Complete,
        self::Closed,
    ];

    private string $value;

    public function __construct(string $value) {
        if (!in_array($value, self::Valid_Statuses)) {
            throw \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Invalid status "%s"', $value));
        }

        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function getValue(): string {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function __toString(): string {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

```php
function mapFromArray($event, $array) {
    if (!is_null($array['EventStatus'])) {
        try {
            $event->eventstatus = new Status($array['EventStatus']);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            // handle invalid status value here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a slightly different method from what was proposed using array values, but still relying on some sort of array to check for allowed values.

In my Events class I extended from abstract class Mapper (within which I added a new performMapping function to make mapping more dynamic)

```
<?php
    namespace data\mapper;
    use app\enums\Status;
    use data\model\Event;

    class Events extends Mapper
    { 
        public function mapFromArray($array) : Event
        {
            $event = $this->_performMapping($array,  new Event());
            return $event;               
        }
    }
```

Model - Added Magic Methods (__set, __get)

```
<?php
    namespace data\model;
    use app\enums\Status;
    
    class Event
    {
        public $eventid;  
        public $riskid;        
        public $eventtitle;
        private $eventstatus;
        public $eventownerid;
        public $actualdate;
        public $scheduledate;
        public $baselinedate;
        public $actuallikelihood;
        public $actualtechnical;
        public $actualschedule;
        public $actualcost;
        public $scheduledlikelihood;
        public $scheduledtechnical;
        public $scheduledschedule;
        public $scheduledcost;
        public $baselinelikelihood;
        public $baselinetechnical;
        public $baselineschedule;
        public $baselinecost;
 
        public function __set($name, $value)
        {
            switch ($name)
            {
                case 'eventstatus':
                {
                    $class = Status::class;
                    try 
                    {
                        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($class);
                    } 
                    catch (\ReflectionException $ex) 
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                
                    $constants = $reflection->getConstants();

                    if (array_key_exists($value, $constants))
                        $this->$name = constant("\\".$class."::$constants[$value]");
                    else
                        throw (new \Exception("Property $name not found in " . $class));
                }
                default:
                {
                    if (property_exists(get_class($this), $name))
                        $this->$name = $value;
                    else
                        throw (new \Exception("Property $name not found in " . get_class($this)));   
                }
            }
        }

        public function __get($name)
        {
            switch ($name)
            {
                case 'eventstatus':
                    return $this->$name;
                default:
                    if (property_exists($this, $name))
                        return $this->$name;
                    else
                        return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Mapper

```
<?php
    namespace data\mapper;

    abstract class mapper
    {
        protected $db = null;
        
        public function __construct(\PDO $db)
        {
            $this->db = $db;
        }
        
        abstract public function mapFromArray($array);

        protected function _populateFromCollection($results = null)
        {
            $return = [];  
            
            if ($results != null)
            {
                foreach($results as $result)
                {
                    $return[] = $this->mapFromArray($result);
                }
            }
            return $return;
        }

        protected function _performMapping($array, $object)
        {
            foreach (array_keys($array) as $property)
            {
                $lowerCaseProperty = strtolower($property);
                if (property_exists(get_class($object), $property))
                    $object->$property = $array[$property];
                else if (property_exists(get_class($object), $lowerCaseProperty))     
                    $object->$lowerCaseProperty = $array[$property];
            }
            return $object;
        }
```

Enum

```
<?php
    namespace app\enums;

    abstract class Status
    {
        const Open = 'Open';
        const Complete = 'Complete';
        const Closed = 'Closed';    
    }
```

Comment: Unclear if making $eventstatus private will prevent intellisense from showing the member variable with magic methods.  That is something I need to research.    If I have introduced an unnecessary problem with a private property like $eventstatus, I would be open to a solution to avoid intellisense issues.