# Get Case from enum by string

Tags: php, enums, php-8.1

I search for a simple solution to get the case of an enum by a string.
There are BackedEnums. For example:

```
<?php
enum Status: string
{
    case OK = "OK";
    case FAILED = "FAILED";
    ...
}
$status = Status::tryFrom("OK"); // or from("OK");
```

But I don't want to write the same word twice for getting that result. Is there a native way to get the case without having BackedEnums?
I want something like:

```
<?php
enum Status
{
    case OK;
    case FAILED;
    ...
}
$status = Status::get("OK"); //returns Status::OK;
```

Or do I need to write my own funcionality for that? For example:

```
enum Status
{
    case OK;
    case FAILED;    
    public static function get(string $name): null|Status
    {
        $name = strtoupper(trim($name));
        if(empty($name))
            return null;

        foreach(Status::cases() as $status)
        {
            if($status->name == $name)
                return $status;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

Status::get("OK"); // -> Status::OK
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ReflectionEnum` is the answer. In the rfc for enums in php8.1 is a chapter [Reflection](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/enumerations#reflection)

There you have the method `getCase(string $name)` and in combination with `getValue()` you get the enum. With that function you can get the case via a string value.

Your Example would look like this:

```
$status = (new ReflectionEnum("Status"))->getCase("OK")->getValue();
```

Best used with an ExceptionHandler since the transmitted string, if not found, could end up in a `ReflectionException`

Comment: Valid value can be tested with `ReflectionEnum::hasCase`

Comment: Class name is better to reference with `Status::class` constant instaed of literal.

Comment: I made it more generic with `self::class` instead of the class name or string

Answer (score 7):

There is an internal name getter like this.

`Status::OK->name;`

This will return `Ok`

`Status::OK->value;`

This will return the value

To get the case from the value. Use this

`$case = Status::tryFrom('Ok')`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/backedenum.tryfrom.php

Comment: A slightly more verbose answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66208862/296555

Comment: my situation is different. I will try to make clear what I mean.
I don't know the case in this example Status::OK 
What i have is a string with the name of the case: "OK"
And now I try to find the simplest generic way to get the case for the string "OK"

Comment: Look at the last line of code i wrote: `Status::get("OK")`. lets suggest that i have a variabel `$test = "OK"` and now I want the matching case from status to that. Is it clear what I mean?

Comment: @philsak, I edited my original response.

Comment: `tryFrom` is not available in a non backed enum and op actually wants to simplify writing his `enums` without values (So non backed)

Answer (score 3):

Only a `BackedEnum` has the `from` and `tryFrom` methods available sadly, but they can easily be *polyfilled*, here is how you could write your own `from` and `tryFrom` in a trait for reusability

```php
<?php

trait LazyEnum
{
    public static function tryFrom($caseName): ?self
    {
        $rc = new ReflectionEnum(self::class);
        return $rc->hasCase($caseName) ? $rc->getConstant($caseName) : null;
    }

    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static function from($caseName): self
    {
        return self::tryFrom($caseName) ?? throw new Exception('Enum '. $caseName . ' not found in ' . self::class);
    }

}


enum Test
{
    use LazyEnum;
    
    case FOO;
    case BAR;
}
var_dump(Test::tryFrom('FOO')); //enum(Test::FOO)
var_dump(Test::tryFrom('BAZ')); //NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own, you could use https://packagist.org/packages/henzeb/enumhancer

This will do for you what you need, and so much more.

Comment: IMHO, it does really too much in the context of this question for a small feature, remember folks, each dependency you add means more maintenance down the road